# jqGrid Custom operations with Edit Dialog fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid that has some editable columns. I'm using the Edit Dialog feature to edit the table rows:
[image: jqGrid edit dialog]

I need the SACOS field to be multiplied (and other operations) with the PESO BRUTO field to obtain the value of COSTO TRANSPORTE. I've tried using JavaScript and/or JQuery selecting their names (obtaining then using Firebug) but nothing works, maybe it's because this little form is inside another form and as we know HTML nested forms are forbidden.

[image: input fields names]

So, how can I perform operations with the edit dialog fields?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use your own jquery dialog with your own button using 'navButtonAdd', in this way you would have total control of your dialog and text fields

Comment: It's really unclear what you need. What you mean under "the SACOS field to be multiplied"? Do you need multiselect dropdown in SACOS field? Do you want to make the dropdown values of SACOS be depend on values from PESO BRUTO and COSTO TRANSPORTE fields? Do you need to do some actions on **change** of some field or you need do some **initialization** changed on opening of Edit dialog?...

Comment: I mean: `COSTO TRANSPORTE = SACOS * PESO BRUTO`. What I need is to do this calculations while user is filling the input fields (when a keyup event is fired).

Comment: I would use my own jquery dialog but I believe this jqGrid edit dialog is what I need, I mean, its features (such as nav buttons) are very functional.